# Efficient way to index float ranges and increase/decrease the index depending on the passed in float value C#

Tags: c#, indexing

so i want to be able to set up and add a bunch of ranges from 0-1 and these ranges be indexed.
First range 0.0f - 0.25f, next will start where last finished
0.25f - 0.36 then lets add another 0.36 - 0.75f and so on, now we have set up our custom ranges(4), I want to be able to as efficiently as possible pass in a value from 0 - 1 and the script knows which current range it belongs in does that code and but once it goes prior or past then the index changes.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i want a array of floats i can add to their start is the finish of the previous, for example 0-0.25, our next ones start will be 0.25 to what ever the new float value is, and so on until it reaches 1, then we pass our main value 0-1 covering all ranges , and that value knows hey execute the code relevant to this range

Comment: i was thinking switch statements or an indexer that compares against start and end current range and if at start or end and goes backwards or forwards the index increases or decreases , but I feel like there is a simpler way

Comment: @NewGuy Please try to provide a working solution before you start caring about efficiency. Then explain why you don't think the solution you have is "efficient" enough for you. A rule of thumb in performance optimization is: don't optimize what doesn't need optimization. It's a waste of time.

Comment: i found something quite handy ~
`(x - min) * (max - x) >= 0 ` ~
Here is a clever method that reduces the number of comparisons from two to one by using some math. The idea is that one of the two factors becomes negative if the number lies outside of the range and zero if the number is equal to one of the bounds , Credit Olivier Jacot-Descombes . i could use this and once it does go over ill then check which range our value now belongs in .

Comment: Unless you provide a solution (or at least a proposal of it) as well as additional data relating to performance requirements and how the proposed solution is insufficient, there's nothing we can do for you. Can you tell if floating point multiplication, two subtractions and a comparison is faster than two comparisons, especially in language like C#? I can't, but my guess is that it isn't. But that is really just a guess. This is why the process here should be creating a solution, benchmarking it with representative dataset and then thinking about how it can be improved - if at all.